# How to avoid Linked Table manager message while opening the Access DB

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

My Application ( Vb.Net) is to scan Access DB forms and find out the Activx control if present and it works fine. But my problem is...

In some DBs we have tables with mapping path to specific locations (Table Property->Linked Table Manager) and when we relocate these DBs then we need to change the path manually otherwise it will show a message to re-link ( Access DB message) while opening the DB. And I am facing same problem while scanning through my Tool as well and my process stops, continue only by manual intervention.

Do I capture the massage event and send some user specific message to user in the Log file or Report and continue scanning further?

Can anyone help me???

Answer (score 0):

I think this is caused by a startup macro that is checking the linked tables. You should disable startup forms and macros when opening the database.

To disable startup forms or autoexec - look here

[how-do-i-bypass-ms-access-startup-when-using-ole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441126/how-do-i-bypass-ms-access-startup-when-using-ole/441223#441223)

or

http://www.mvps.org/access/api/api0068.htm

Comment: Could you let me know the links or any code, how to do this programmetically.

Thank you

Comment: This was also suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435206/how-to-restrict-ms-access-db-to-open

Comment: Sorry Remou - I should have linked to your answer instead of stealing the link :-)

Comment: I Have tried using API, But it is not working...also not showing any error. Please let me know any other way of approach.